# How to find, whether the certificate is a private certificate or a public certificate

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I have to write a MSI, where in i have to give only the public certicate. In case the user gives a private certificate, it should pop up an error message.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "private certificate" or "public certificate". There exist a certificate with embedded public key and a corresponding private key (usually kept separately). You probably need to check presence of private key with the passed certificate, but the way to do this depends on the way used to pass this certificate.